# Checking for the availability of props before invoking/using them in Vue Templates, to avoid expections for my applications

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuex

I am new to Vue and currently building a small application that consists of several components and uses a Vuex store. This store is fed with information from a normal Python REST Api.

This backend is maintained by different people, so I want to check in my templates if certain keys are available in the used objects.

Of course I could now wrap all places with a v-if, but that seems wrong to me somehow.

Is there a better way to check for the presence of the keys in my templates?

Edit: Im using Vue 2.

Comment: The question doesn't mention Vue version. 3 has suspense which suits the case. 2 has none, but you could postpone initial rendering until the store is filled.

Comment: Thank you for your quick comment! I'm currently using Vue 2, but the suspend feature of Vue 3 seems to do exactly what I'm looking for. Is wrapping props in v-ifs the only way for Vue 2?

Comment: See the remark regarding initial rendering. If you made data available in global store before rendering components that depend on it, it's available on initial rendering. With local state you're limited to v-if.